# Time complexity of a function which check if a number is power of two numbers

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I wrote a solution to check if a number(N) can be represented as

[image: eq]

where A > 0 and P > 1. I think the complexity of this solution is O([image: complexity])

But I am not sure about the base of the log and I do not have a mathematical explanation, I just understand the working of the loop which helped me come to my conclusion.

```
public int isPower(int A) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(A); i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= (Math.log(A) / Math.log(i)); j++) {
            if ((int)Math.pow(i, j) == A)
                return 1;
        }
    }
    return (A == 1) ? 1: 0;
}
```

I am preparing for interviews and any solution would be greatly appreciated and will help me prepare better. Also if you think this problem can be done faster than my algorithm let me know.

Comment: @AshvinSharma What is the question?

Comment: Check first two lines of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for correcting the solution Ashwin.

You don't need to iterate the second loop completely again and can do only one value check. The sample code will look like this.

```
public int isPower(int a) {
        if (a == 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        for (long i = 2; i * i <= a; i++) {
            final double value = Math.log(a) / Math.log(i);
            if (value - (int) value < 0.00000001) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

The complexity of this solution O(sqrt(n)).  I think this is the most efficient solution.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Can you confirm if it is working for `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: UPDATE: Indeed it is working but it took 92554ms vs 14ms(my algo) on my machine.

Comment: Also, it's better to change the variable "i" to long to avoid overflow. I have updated the answer, can you try again.

Comment: yep, long did the trick now it is definitely faster than mine :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better solution would be to prime factorize the number and then see if the powers of prime numbers have a GCD not equal to one.
If you didn't understand what I've written, I can explain it better with a code.

Comment: With GCD it will be O(log(n)), but how can I check powers with gcd?. If you can write a program it would be easier to understand. :)

Comment: You just create a new variable for each prime number and see how many times, they're repeating